# How do I get my button inline (next to) the input?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

The button in my header is doing this really annoying thing where is dropping below the input form. I've searched online & seen the different answers people have given to similar issues but none of them are working for me. Below is an image of the problem. Can anybody figure out what I'm missing?

[image]

```css
.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
button.btn.btn-secondary {
  display: inline-block;
}
#product-search-btn {
  padding 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form">
  <input type='textbox' name="s" class="form-control form-inline" id="item-search" placeholder="Enter your postcode.." />
  <input class="btn btn-secondary no-border " id="product-search-btn" type="submit" class="search-submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Mix float + inline-block have no sense.

Comment: @Epodax are you happy now? Hope it didn't affect your day too much.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I'm looking for help, not criticism. Thanks.

Comment: you must have some other css somewhere, i started a fiddle and they are side by side https://jsfiddle.net/dckqLrnr/

Comment: It's a help. If you treat that sentence as constructive, you will not mix no more float + inline-block, because float overrides that value. However, you are using bootstrap, that has a grid system to avoid your problem. Onl yput inside the form two columns and it works.

Comment: @PaulLedger he has a complete bootstrap CSS

Comment: @TAA if you find criticism in all help you've got you will have a problem in this site.

Comment: It's because I'm using Bootstrap and overriding Wordpress. I'll look deeper into the code. Thank you. @PaulLedger

Comment: KInd of explains a lot, Im not too familiar with bootstrap but the grid system will allow you to use columns to stack all elements in your header side by side

Answer (score 4):

See my fiddle

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="">
  <input class="btn btn-secondary no-border " id="product-search-btn" type="submit" class="search-submit" />
  <input type='textbox' name="s" class="form-control form-inline" id="item-search" value="" placeholder="Enter your postcode.." />
</form>
```

and css

```
.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#item-search {
  width: 70%;
}

button.btn.btn-secondary {
  display: inline-block;
}

#product-search-btn {
  padding 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hyk18g88/

You need to set the width for text input to let the button float next to it

You can also use bootstrap grid system, see the doc for that :)

---------- EDIT ---------------

Ok, as stated in comments, there a lot of incongruences.

I updated the fiddle to try to make things more clear.

I still did not use the bootstrap grid system, to avoid make confusion.

This problem is only a matter of width

https://jsfiddle.net/hyk18g88/2/

Let me know what you think

Comment: You're a God sent! Thank you very much, that worked great.

Comment: Doesn't work in firefox at least. However, you are mixing floats and inline-blocks...... that's no sense, I insist.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude check my updated fiddle

Comment: It works perfectly now! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.search-form {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
}
```

Try replacing your **search-form** class with the above properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the column css thing:

On the css file add:

```
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}



[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Then in you html add the "col-[size]" class property to your tags. The container tag should have in its class "col-12" to specify it occupates the whole width. And tags inside the container should carry "col-8" and "col-4" for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=\'utf-8\'/>
    <title>test</title> 

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form col-12">
  <input type='textbox' name="s" class="form-control form-inline col-8" id="item-search" placeholder="Enter your postcode.." />
  <input class="btn btn-secondary no-border col-4" id="product-search-btn" type="submit" class="search-submit" />
</form>
</body>
```